# How can I catch a global cursor icon change event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, system

I want a global hook to the mouse and have an event fire when the cursor changes to an Ibeam or any other cursor icon types.

Comment: Use an accessibility hook. Listen for EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE on OBJID_CURSOR. (The real question is why you care. Let the cursor do its thing without interference.)

Comment: The reason I want to do it is I'm making a mouseless/keyboard-less interface for windows. When the cursor changes to an Ibeam I want an onscreen keyboard to pop up. I've tried using SetWinEventHook but I have not gotten it to work. Do you have a code example I could use? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Better would be to respond to focus entering an edit control. Otherwise you're going to be popping up the keyboard when you shouldn't. See the System.Windows.Automation namespace, which lets you subscribe to specific events in a C#-friendly way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Win32 article in a [MSDN Magazine issue back from 2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301524.aspx) that seems to cover that topic.

If the idea they discuss in their article fits to your requirements, I do think that you can use the ideas within the article and use some P/Invoke to do this in C#.